# Numpy np.any range or threshold

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, rgb

I am using python, OpenCV and Numpy.  My goal is to find all white pixel and turn it red and turn everything else off or white.  My code:

```
 import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Read mask
    image = cv2.imread("path to my image")

    any_white = np.any(image == [255,255,255], axis = -1)

    image[any_white]=[255,0,0]
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()

cv2.imwrite('result.png',image)
```

Problem 1: Targetting any `[255,255,255]` doesn't find all, whiteist, I starting finding any `[244,244,244]`, `[243,243,243]` and so on.  Is there a way to set a range of white, maybe from `[255,255,255]` to `[230,230,230]`?

[image]

Problem 2: clearly, with `plt.imshow(image)` and `plt.show()` within python, the result shows red, but when i used `cv2.imwrite('result.png',image)` to save, it's blue.  See result image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1: 
You can create a mask and set the red channel to `False` so that you keep the value at 255 if you want to target only the white pixels

```
mask_bg = (image == [255, 255, 255])
mask_bg[:, :, 0] = False  # set red channel mask to false (leave 255 value)

image[mask_bg] = 0  # set all white pixels to [255, 0, 0]
```

If you want to find all values in a range you can use `cv2.inRange`:

```
mask = cv2.inRange(image, (230, 230, 230), (255, 255,255))
```

Problem 2:
OpenCV uses BGR as default instead of RGB, you can convert from BGR to RGB with:

```
new_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imshow('BGR Image', new_image )
```

Keep in mind that if you open an image with OpenCV it will be BGR, so convert it before manipulating the channels.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**
The pixels you are planning to target may not have the exact value of `(255, 255, 255)`. Hence it is better to binarize the image by setting a range of pixel values. You can find the exact range by creating Trackbars and tuning them manually. You can find more about implementing Trackbars in OpenCV [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html#trackbar).

**Problem 2:**
This happens because OpenCV uses `BGR` or `(Blue, Green, Red)` colorspace by default. You can change the colorspace into `RGB` or `(Red, Green, Blue)` by using `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` before saving.